# How can I animate this double pendulum?

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations, animate

I want to visualize an animation of a double pendulum, but I don't know how to do it, since I'm new to the `animate` package, here's the code of the double pendulum (tikz) :

```
    \documentclass[tikz,border=8mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,angles,quotes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
angle eccentricity=1.2,
ball/.style={circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2mm, fill=blue, draw=blue, label=right:$m$},
background rectangle/.style={fill=black},
show background rectangle]

\draw[thick, white] (-2,0) --(2,0);
\draw[white] (0,0) coordinate (b0) foreach \i [count=\ni] in {-70,-55} {--++(\i:2cm) node[midway,auto]{$l$} node[ball] (b\ni) {}};

\foreach \i [count=\auxi] in {b0,b1}{
    \draw[dashed, white] (\i)--++(-90:1.8cm) coordinate[pos=.75] (aux\auxi);
} 

\draw pic["$\theta_1$", draw, white, angle radius=1.2cm] {angle=aux1--b0--b1};
\draw pic["$\theta_2$", draw, white, angle radius=1.2cm] {angle=aux2--b1--b2};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: tik]

Comment: You would have to solve the equation of motion (ordinary diff equation) to calculate theta_1 and theta_2 as a function of time. You could do this within LaTeX with pkg `pst-ode` and draw the animation frames with PSTricks.

Comment: ... or with Ti*k*Z, as shown below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(Plotting animation frames with TikZ)

To animate the double pendulum, we have to solve the equation of motion, which is a set of Ordinary Differential Equations (ODE). For the friction-less double-pendulum of two different point masses, the differential equations for the swing angles *θ*<sub>1</sub> and *θ*<sub>2</sub> are given at the end of section 1 in this french Wikipedia article:

[https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendule_double#Mise_en_%C3%A9quation_utilisant_l'approche_lagrangienne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendule_double#Mise_en_%C3%A9quation_utilisant_l%27approche_lagrangienne)

Both equations (1) & (2) are implicit and coupled in the angular accelerations. To make the first one explicit, Eq. (2) is substituted into (1) and (1) is resolved for `\ddot{`*θ*<sub>1</sub>`}`.

To solve the system of ODEs within LaTeX, we can use package `pst-ode` (method: **RKF45**). It is a PSTricks package, but thanks to [luapstricks](https://ctan.org/pkg/luapstricks), a PostScript interpreter by Marcel Krüger, the example below can be typeset directly with `lualatex`; `ps2pdf` (Ghostscript) is no longer needed.

The file `timeTheta1Theta2.dat` written during the first run is read line by line to get time and the angles at each step. The animation frames are finally plotted with `TikZ`.

These are the parameters you may want to play with:

```
/tEnd 70 def                                % time span to be simulated [s]
/m1 1 def                                   % mass1 [kg]
/m2 1 def                                   % mass2 [kg]
/l1 2 def                                   % pendulum1 length [m]
/l2 2 def                                   % pendulum2 length [m]
/G 9.81 def                                 % acceleration [m/s^2]
/theta1zero 179 Pi mul 180 div def          % theta1_0=179°
/theta2zero 180 Pi mul 180 div def          % theta2_0=180°
```

Realtime animation over 70 s. Click to run animation (If Firefox is too slow, try a Chromium-based browser instead.)

[image]

Typeset three times with `lualatex`:

```latex
%\PassOptionsToPackage{dvisvgm}{animate} % dvilualatex <file> ; dvisvgm --zoom=-1 --font-format=woff2 --bbox=papersize <file>.dvi 
\documentclass[margin=1mm,varwidth]{standalone} 
 
\usepackage{pst-ode} 
\usepackage[controls,autoplay]{animate} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{listofitems} % read space separated items 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{xfp} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
 
% adjustable parameters & definitions 
\pstVerb{ 
  tx@Dict begin 
  /tEnd 70 def                                % time span to be simulated [s] 
  /m1 1 def                                   % mass1 [kg] 
  /m2 1 def                                   % mass2 [kg] 
  /l1 2 def                                   % pendulum1 length [m] 
  /l2 2 def                                   % pendulum2 length [m] 
  /G 9.81 def                                 % acceleration [m/s^2] 
  /theta1zero 179 Pi mul 180 div def          % theta1_0=179° 
  /theta2zero 180 Pi mul 180 div def          % theta2_0=180° 
  /N (cvi(tEnd*25+1)) AlgParser cvx exec def  % (integer) number of time steps (for 25 frames per s) + 1 
  % 
  /M2 (m2/(m1+m2)) AlgParser cvx exec def     % some constants 
  /rM2 (1/M2) AlgParser cvx exec def 
  /l12 (l1/l2) AlgParser cvx exec def 
  /l21 (l2/l1) AlgParser cvx exec def 
  /G1 (G/l1) AlgParser cvx exec def 
  /G2 (G/l2) AlgParser cvx exec def 
  /G1M2 (G1/M2) AlgParser cvx exec def 
  % 
  /theta1Dot (x[2]) AlgParser cvx def         % 1st order ODE system 
  /theta2Dot (x[3]) AlgParser cvx def 
  /omega1Dot (((G1*sin(x[1])-x[2]^2*sin(x[0]-x[1]))*cos(x[0]-x[1])-l21*x[3]^2*sin(x[0]-x[1])-G1M2*sin(x[0])) 
    /(rM2-cos(x[0]-x[1])^2)) AlgParser cvx def 
  /omega2Dot (-l12*(omega1Dot*cos(x[0]-x[1])-x[2]^2*sin(x[0]-x[1]))-G2*sin(x[1])) AlgParser cvx def 
  end 
} 
 
% solve equations of motion 
\pstODEsolve[algebraicAll,saveData]{timeTheta1Theta2}{% PS variable that takes result list 
  t | x[0]*180/Pi-90 | x[1]*180/Pi-90 % table format of data to be saved in timeTheta1Theta2 
}{0}{tEnd}{N}{                        % t_0, t_end, number of  time steps + 1 
  theta1zero | theta2zero | 0 | 0     % initial conditions 
}{ 
  theta1Dot | theta2Dot | omega1Dot | omega2Dot  % ODE system's RHS 
} 
 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
% \fileopenr{<file stream>}{<file name>}, opens file for reading 
\newcommand\fileopenr[2]{% 
  \newread#1% 
  \immediate\openin#1=#2% 
} 
% \readtolist[<sep char>]{<file stream>}{\list} 
% reads a line from file stream and splits at <sep char> into \list[1], \list[2], ... 
\newcommand\readtolist[3][,]{{% 
  \setsepchar{#1}% 
  \immediate\read#2 to \inputline% 
    \ifeof#2 
      \immediate\closein#2% 
      \ifdefined\multiframebreak\multiframebreak\fi% 
    \else% 
      \greadlist*#3\inputline% 
    \fi% 
}} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
 
\begin{document} 
 
$l_1=l_2=\qty{2}{\metre}$; $m_1=m_2=\qty{1}{\kilogram}$\\ 
\IfFileExists{timeTheta1Theta2.dat}{}{\end{document}}% 
\begin{animateinline}{25} 
  \fileopenr{\data}{timeTheta1Theta2.dat}% 
  \readtolist[ ]{\data}{\table}% 
  \multiframe{100000}{}{ 
    \begin{tikzpicture}% 
      \useasboundingbox (-4.2,-4.2) rectangle (4.2,4.2); 
      \filldraw (0,0) -- ++(\table[2]:2) circle[radius=1mm] -- ++(\table[3]:2) circle[radius=1mm]; 
      \filldraw [fill=white] (0,0) circle [radius=1pt]; 
      \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt] at (-4.2,4.2) {\strut$t=\qty{\fpeval{trunc(\table[1])}}{\second}$}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}% 
    \readtolist[ ]{\data}{\table}% 
  } 
\end{animateinline} 
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Amazing! Do you have an mechanical  engineering background?

Comment: Chemical engineering, and a lot of procrastination for whatelse is needed.

Comment: The equations to be solved I simply copied, without understanding, from the Wikipedia article.

Comment: I see! Cool that this is within the capability of TeX and friends.

Comment: The true master writes on this blog (in French):  http://pstricks.blogspot.com/

Comment: Cool, thanks for that info!

Comment: On http://pstricks.blogspot.com/, search for "pst-ode animate". Very nice examples will be shown!

Comment: Will do! Do you by any chance have a profile on LinkedIn etc? Would be cool to connect. I am in California, recently moved here from Germany.

Comment: https://what-are-you-looking.at/?page_id=18

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120559/discussion-between-dr-manuel-kuehner-and-alexg).