# How to relabel specific code in tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/586209/240248) code to generate the image of the double pendulum. But I want to relabel the lower link and lower mass with $l_{2}$ and $m_{2}$, respectively. I tried different ways to do that but failed to compile the file in the desired way. Can someone help me out? Thank you.

Comment: I do not know why my "l" and "m" are in math mode? Can someone explain that as well?

Comment: The question in the comment has an easy answer: They are in math mode for reasons of type-setting conventions. They are variables, therefore they are in italics (realised by using math mode).

Comment: Considering how you must re-write the code to remove the for-loops, it will be a lot easier, if you posted your code instead of linking to the other question. In principle, it will compile with `$m_2$` as a lable, but then of course both masses will be labeled as mass 2, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Labelling the upper half using `l_1`/ `m_1`, while the lower half is labelled with `l_2`/ `m_2` would be achieveable without removing the for-loops. If this is an acceptable output, just replace `$m$` with `$m_{\ni}$` and `$l$` with `$m_{\ni}$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by un-entangling the loops, I ended up with this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=8mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        angle eccentricity=1.2,
        ball/.style={circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2mm, fill=blue, draw=blue},
        background rectangle/.style={fill=black},
        show background rectangle]
        
        \draw[thick, white] (-2,0) --(2,0);     
        \draw[white] (0,0) coordinate (b0) -- ++(-70:2cm) node[midway,auto]{$l$} node[ball, label=right:$m$] (b1) {} --++(-55:2cm) node[midway,auto]{$l_2$} node[ball, label=right:$m_2$] (b2) {};
        
        \draw[dashed, white] (b0)--++(-90:1.8cm) coordinate[pos=.75] (aux1);
        \draw[dashed, white] (b1)--++(-90:1.8cm) coordinate[pos=.75] (aux2);
                
        \draw pic["$\theta_1$", draw, white, angle radius=1.2cm] {angle=aux1--b0--b1};
        \draw pic["$\theta_2$", draw, white, angle radius=1.2cm] {angle=aux2--b1--b2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And following the suggestion by @leandriis from the comments, you can do this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=8mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        angle eccentricity=1.2,
        ball/.style={circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2mm, fill=blue, draw=blue, label=right:$m_{\ni}$},
        background rectangle/.style={fill=black},
        show background rectangle]
        
        \draw[thick, white] (-2,0) --(2,0);
        \draw[white] (0,0) coordinate (b0) foreach \i [count=\ni] in {-70,-55} {--++(\i:2cm) node[midway,auto]{$l_{\ni}$} node[ball] (b\ni) {}};
        
        \foreach \i [count=\auxi] in {b0,b1}{
            \draw[dashed, white] (\i)--++(-90:1.8cm) coordinate[pos=.75] (aux\auxi);
        } 
        
        \draw pic["$\theta_1$", draw, white, angle radius=1.2cm] {angle=aux1--b0--b1};
        \draw pic["$\theta_2$", draw, white, angle radius=1.2cm] {angle=aux2--b1--b2};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```